# High Unrestored log on secondary database mirror server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, mirroring

I need your help in understanding/resolving one of the issues we are witnessing today.

We have a high value of unrestored log on secondary side where value keep ranging from 5-10 GB as monitored.

Simultaneously we have a job to create snapshot on this mirror [for reporting] server every 30 minutes which completes within a minute when unrestored is within MB's but keep running for 2-3 hours with high value of unrestored log

The database here is 10 TB and OLTP with DB in high PERformance mode.

Could someone explain why the snapshot job is running that long or how to find it and fix high unrestored value?

Or could it be Vice-versa and i am thinking wrong as mirror causing snapshot to run that long?

Comment: Did an index rebuild job run recently?

Comment: Trying to better understand.  You are talking about the snapshot taking < 1 min and the restore taking 2-3 hours?  Thanks

Comment: @TaraKizer: No maintenance jibs are running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We have a high value of unrestored log on secondary side where value keep ranging from 5-10 GB as monitored.

That's definitely a problem even in high performance (async) mode.

> Simultaneously we have a job to create snapshot on this mirror [for reporting] server every 30 minutes which completes within a minute when unrestored is within MB's but keep running for 2-3 hours with high value of unrestored log
>
> Could someone explain why the snapshot job is running that long or how to find it and fix high unrestored value?

Creating a snapshot of a database causes the snapshot to run recovery - just as if you were to start up any database in SQL Server. Since there is 10 GB of log to go through... it's going to take a while to run recovery. Pair that with adding of more log to an already behind database and you have yourself a great recipe for never catching up and always being behind.

[From BOL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187054(v=sql.105).aspx): Uncommitted transactions are rolled back in a newly created database snapshot because the Database Engine runs recovery after the snapshot has been created (transactions in the database are not affected).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. yes i can see that when i have disabled the Snapshot agent job, mirror has no latency in unrestored log since then . The value is always within 500 MB.. So what options do i have? There is no way i can run snapshot agent job here? We have one more similar server with same config of 10 TB, but snapshot job and mirror hardly gives that much a hard time. What are we missing here then?

Comment: @BeginnerDBA You're on 2012, if you don't want to upgrade to a newer version (not sure on edition you're running right now) there are Availability Groups which have readable secondary replicas. It does require enterprise edition. Additionally you could do a backup and restore as that wouldn't hurt the source database like a snapshot does. I'd still upgrade, if possible, to 2016 and use an AG as there have been more enhancements added.

Comment: Thanks @Sean. But upgrade is not the feasible option here. as of today we see the snapshot running in10-15 mins but unrestored log all the time up to 8 GB.. Just wandering why?